# Block with images with random positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

Does anybody can tell, how I can make such a block with images if we have an array of images with random items

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS Script for this purpose.

```js
function getRandomImage()
{
    var randomImage = new Array();
    randomImage[0] = "https://wi.wallpapertip.com/wsimgs/15-155208_desktop-puppy-wallpaper-hd.jpg";
    randomImage[1] = "http://www.petsworld.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/running-cute-puppies.jpg";
    randomImage[2] = "https://wi.wallpapertip.com/wsimgs/156-1564365_golden-retriever-puppy-desktop-wallpaper-desktop-wallpaper-puppy.jpg";
    randomImage[3] = "https://wi.wallpapertip.com/wsimgs/156-1564140_free-puppy-wallpapers-for-computer-wallpaper-cave-cute.jpg";
    randomImage[4] = "https://wi.wallpapertip.com/wsimgs/156-1565522_puppies-desktop-wallpaper-desktop-background-puppies.jpg";
    randomImage[5] = "https://wi.wallpapertip.com/wsimgs/156-1566650_cute-puppies-desktop-wallpaper-cute-puppies.jpg";
    for (let i=0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<img style="border-radius: 50%; width: 20%" src="'+ randomImage[number] +'" style="width:150px" />';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img style="border-radius: 50%; width: 20%" src="'+ randomImage[number] +'" style="width:150px" />';
        }       
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "getRandomImage()">Generate Image</button>
<br /><br />
<span id="result" align="center"></span>
```